# If question gets deleted by moderator, why not include user with reason as to why?

Tags: feature-request, notifications, deleted-questions

If a question gets deleted by a moderator, why doesn't the user who submitted question get notified as to why?

I have submitted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254176/learning-to-make-a-website), and it was deleted without warning. Why not at least notify me with an explanation so I could understand what to avoid?

Comment: That specific question was closed by five _users_ and deleted by three different _users_. No moderators were involved.

Comment: It was closed 15 hours before it was deleted, and it was deleted for the same reason it was closed: *"closed as not constructive - This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. See the FAQ."* Given that there is generally time between closing and deleting, and the reason is given when closed, there's no particular reason to give another notice when closed, especially since one can ask here if one missed the closing.

Comment: I think one mistake new users make when they ask a question is that they don't understand how quickly they'll receive responses. Thus, they drop the question on SO, then wander off, coming back some time later. My advice: Don't ask a question you're not anticipating monitoring regularly for responses/activity.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I agree with you, but this was not the case as i had read most responses from the first 2 hours, then i needed to go came back and question was deleted.

Comment: @sarnold I do not agree with reason, as question was asking for concise steps based on peoples expertise. this isn't an opinion question as there are steps that all take in the way, there might be a few paths but in most questions there are multiple paths to solve issue. i believe it is a good question in the sense that experts with facts at hand can point out based on experience what is needed. Im Sorry you dont see it my way.

Comment: Then you missed nothing -- the last addition to the question was 19 minutes after you asked it. :) (Well, I can't see deleted _comments_, but those are usually worthless anyhow, just like this one! ;)

Comment: @James: many thanks for being one of the politest users when a question was deleted. :)

Comment: It should be noted that the community voted to close and delete your question, not a *moderator*.

Comment: Far as your actual question goes, you may find [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-web-development) helpful.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312666/162102

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Now that I've taken the time to read the question and answers, I'm not surprised the question was closed -- it is *very* open ended. You could realistically spend three or four semesters in a university setting learning HTML, JavaScript, relational database systems (or non-relational database systems), and servlet or other server-side frameworks. It's *huge*.

We like our questions and our answers to be relatively concise and *best* if there's a handful of specific answers that can be compared and contrasted. There's no way that anyone could select a single "best" answer from a question like yours, and that is our main criteria.

<strike>If that question would have any life anywhere, it *might* have had one on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq), but note that even though they are more willing to accept subjective questions, it might still be closed as too broad.</strike> The [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) site wouldn't be a better fit; from their FAQ: *... and it is not about ... what language you should learn next, including which technology is better ...*. While this doesn't exactly describe your question, it comes pretty close.

I've personally looked into Ruby on Rails, Sinatra, Nitrogen, Chicago Boss, and Django web server-side frameworks, and this is a *small*, minuscule portion of the server-side landscape. Similar stories exist for the client-side landscape: hand-written Javascript, jQuery and its associated plugins, prototype.js and scriptaculous, Flash or Flex, Silverlight, Java applets, etc.

It's just too big for it be handled well here.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to review question, i understand your reasoning although i do not completely agree with it, as answer could have been a short list of overview steps with out delving into all the frameworks and such, but then again i am no expert so alas will try and phrase better for next time. thank you.

Comment: `If that question would have any life anywhere, it might have had one on [programmers], but note that even though they are more willing to accept subjective questions, it might still be closed as too broad.` Can't see the actual question, but as a rule of thumb: If a question was closed on SO as not constructive / not a real question / too localized, please **don't** suggest P.SE as an alternative. No chance we want it.

Comment: @Yannis: thanks for the clarification. :)

Comment: There are rare exceptions, of course, but as a rule of thumb...

Comment: @YannisRizos Looking into [Programmers], i noticed the top voted [question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-should-every-programmer-know-about-web-development.) is pretty much my own question, with a great answer. thanks for the advice ;)

Comment: Wow, the first two answers are excellent. Woot! :)

Comment: @james Glad to hear that. Still, if asked today we would probably close it. What saved it, is probably the [community effort](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/posts/46760/revisions) that went into the highest voted answer.

Comment: James, another question (not yet closed...) that you might find helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744906/would-you-recommend-starting-from-html5-css3-for-beginners/4744994#4744994

Comment: @sarnold thank you, it was very helpful.